# Eigenvalues come in pairs

Tags: linear-algebra, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices, eigenvalues, singular-values

Consider the two matrices with some parameter $s \in \mathbb R$

$$A_1= \begin{pmatrix} s& -1 &0& 0 \\1&0 &0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\0&0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$A_2= \begin{pmatrix} s& -1 &-1& 0 \\1&0 &0&0 \\ -1&0&s&-1 \\0&0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

I then noticed that the eigenvalues of arbitrary products of $A_1$ and $A_2$, i.e. e.g. $A_1A_2A_1$ and $A_1A_1A_2A_1$ etc. all have eigenvalues $\lambda_1,1/\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2, 1/\lambda_2.$

It is clear that the product of eigenvalues is equal to one, as both matrices are in $\text{SL}(4,\mathbb R)$, but I don't see why they have to come in two pairs that multiply up to one, respectively.

Comment: Likely, $A_1$ and $A_2$ belong to a classical group $G$, defined by the identity $A^TJA=J$ for some invertible $J$ (which you must find). Then $JAJ^{-1}=A^{-T}$ tells you that the spectrum if invariant under $\lambda\mapsto\lambda^{-1}$.

Comment: @DenisSerre thanks. Based on Carlo Beenakker's answer, this is true as $A_1^{-1} = UA_1U$. Thus $A_1^{-T}=VA_1^{-1}V=VUA_1 UV.$ Thus $J=VU.$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This follows from the identities
$$A_1^{-1}=UA_1U^{-1},\;\;A_2^{-1}=UA_2U^{-1},$$
$$A_1^{\top}=VA_1V^{-1},\;\;A_2^{\top}=VA_2V^{-1},$$
with
$$U=U^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;V=V^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
Hence for any string of products $M=A_1^{n_1}A_2^{n_2}A_1^{n_3}A_2^{n_4}\cdots A_1^{n_N-1}A_2^{n_N}$ of the two matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ one has
$$M^\top = VU M^{-1} (VU)^{-1}.$$
It follows that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, then also $1/\lambda$ is an eigenvalue:
$${\rm det}\,(\lambda-M)={\rm det}\,(\lambda-M^\top)={\rm det}\,(\lambda-VU M^{-1}(VU)^{-1})={\rm det}\,(\lambda-M^{-1}),$$
which implies that
$${\rm det}\,(\lambda-M)=0\Leftrightarrow {\rm det}\,(\lambda^{-1}-M)=0.$$
The case $\lambda=0$ is excluded because $A_1$ and $A_2$ are nonsingular for any $s$.

Comment: Hm, how does it follow? I see how it would follow from identities $A_i^{-1}=VA_i^{t}V^{-1}$ for $i=1,2$

Comment: I added the intermediate steps

Comment: In the second-to-last displayed equation, is the middle term really what you mean, or should it be the transpose of the matrix $A_2^{n_N} A_1^{n_{N_1}} \dots A_2^{n_4} A_1^{n_3} A_2^{n_2} A_1^{n_1}$ you get by multiplying in the opposite order?

Comment: @WillSawin --- I have added some further intermediate steps.